# Internet Explorer 11 doesn't render Image

Tags: angularjs, svg, typescript, internet-explorer-11

I have a Web-App written in Typescript with Angular. 
This displays a huge SVG element with d3js and renders many smaller SVGs on it, at least 100. It also has a header, that is a .png image. This image is not rendered in IE11, in fact, after inspecting the DOM IE removes the whole  element from it.

This is my code for rendering the .png.

```
<img ng-controller="Ctrl as ctrl" src="images/logo.png" class="logo" 
       tooltip="{{'version' | translate:ctrl.version}}" tooltip-placement="bottom"/>
```

If you refresh the page, it shows for a second, then get's removed.

This only happens in IE, not in Firefox or Chrome.

Comment: If you are saying that the header image is inside the SVG, then `<img>` is the wrong element to use. You would need to use `<image xlink:href="images/logo.png" x="" y="" width="" height="">`.

Comment: It's not inside the SVG, it's just in the header, standard html.